# Why is there no EFI boot loader on the Ubuntu 12.10 x64 Netinstall? (mini.iso)

Tags: boot, 12.10, uefi, alternate

Im trying to boot the netinstall(mini.iso) toasted to an usb-stick, but there is no EFI loader in that iso image. so it is not possible to load that kind of installation type on an efi powered system.

In my desperation I copied the /EFI folder with its loader from the desktop install media to my netinstall usb-stick. dont know if this way is legit, but it loaded the installer screen. but big problem is, that the installer-screen is horrible distorted so I cant see anything and cant install. also the installer seems to pressed into the upper half of the screen and has a high resolution (because it seems small, what I can see).

BTW the desktop iso boots successfully. But Im using a complex setup of encrypted lvm with multiple drives wich can not be setup by desktop-installer in that scale, so I need the debian-based-installer. Since alternate iso's have been discontinued, the netinstall media is my last option. I hope you can understand and respect my usage scenario.

I know with every release ubuntu is more less willing to support professional users and focus on normal home users, but Im loyal and realy want to continue using ubuntu. So Im also hoping for your help.

Comment: as of now, the newest netinstall images include efi. and it looks like 12.04 even has it now